# Rolling/sliding on an incline with/without friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

Suppose I roll down a hollow sphere and a solid sphere with the same mass and radius down an incline. Which one will reach the bottom first? If there is sufficient friction, the solid sphere will reach first. But if there is no friction, will both of them reach at the same time? Is this much information [not given if incline is rough or smooth] enough to conclude which sphere will reach first?

Answer (score 1):

> If there is sufficient friction, the solid sphere will reach first.

In the case of pure *rolling without sliding* (slipping), yes.

> But if their is no friction, will both of them reach at the same time?

In the case of pure *sliding without rolling*, yes.

Comment: Could you explain why, if both objects have the same mass, radius and therefore centre of mass there would be any difference? I would have thought the normal reaction force from the plane etc etc would be identical in the two scenarios.

Comment: It is explained by Conservation of Energy. When the balls are rolling (or sliding) down the incline gravitational potential energy is converted to kinetic energy. But in the case of rolling, the kinetic energy is split between translational and rotational KE. A solid sphere (all other things being equal) has more rotational KE because its moment of inertial is higher than for a hollow sphere.

Comment: Sorry, that should have read: *A hollow sphere (all other things being equal) has more rotational KE because its moment of inertial is higher than for a solid sphere.*

Comment: Ah, this will be much more obvious after my current term's course on rotational dynamics. Thank you.

Comment: I want to know that if the question says they are allowed to roll down an incline, is it right to assume that the incline must be rough as rolling is not possible on a smooth incline?